# Changing format of Heroku CLI logs' timestamps

Tags: shell, logging, heroku, command-line-interface

Currently, when you check you app's logs with Heroku CLI using `heroku logs`, the timestamp format is the following:

```
2018-03-07T08:07:27.683252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: - State changed from starting to up
```

which I find too detailed.

Is there any command for my Heroku app environment to set logger timestamp format?

I want to trim the suffix after seconds to make it look like this:

```
2018-03-07T08:07:27 heroku[web.1]: - State changed from starting to up
```

*Just a side-note: this is not my python app's timestamp format but Heroku's one*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not something you can do.
Using a log retention system (there are [several add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) doing so), you may be able to do so though.

Comment: I've used Papertail as a logging frontend and it's indeed a solution, but I'd rather prefer having a nicely-formatted console output for my purpose. Thank you for your answer, I'll accept that.